# Join query for time range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

MAP

```
Product    Channel  ProgDate   AdvTime
Air    Pix  30-04-2011  20:57:16
Air    Pix  30-05-2011  00:55:08
```

MBA

```
Product    Channel Date   ProgStartTime ProgEndTime
Air    Pix  30-04-2011  23:00:00   02:00:00
Air    Pix  30-04-2011  21:00:00   22:00:00
```

I have to check whether AdvtTime in MAP is between the `StartTime` & `EndTime` in MBA table.

But when the duration (`ProgStartTime` - `ProgEndTime`) is one hour I need a buffer of + or - 5 mins.

I need
`00:05:08 to match 23:00:00` to `02:00:00`, and
`20:57:16 to match 21:00:00` to `22:00:00`.

I used the below query to join

```
Select Distinct mb.Id as mbaid,mp.id as mapid, mp.Channel as Channel, mp.Product,mp.ProgDate, mp.AdvTime, mb.Channel,  mb.ProgStartTime, 
  mb.ProgEndTime, convert(time, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, mb.progStartTime, mb.progEndTime), 0)) as timeDiff from map22 as mp inner join mba22 as mb 
on ((mp.ProgDate = mp.ProgDate and mp.Channel=mb.Channel and mp.Product=mb.Product)) 
 where (mp.ProgDate = mb.ProgDate
           AND AdvTime >= ProgStartTime
           AND (AdvTime <= ProgEndTime OR ProgEndTime < ProgStartTime))
          OR
          (mp.ProgDate = Dateadd(day,1,mb.ProgDate)
           AND ProgEndTime < ProgStartTime
           AND AdvTime <= ProgEndTime)
order by  mp.Id asc
```

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477708/sql-join-with-a-buffer-time

Comment: Am sorry but i didnt get the proper result there as my question wasnt clearly framed. Can someone pls help me for this scenario

Comment: Can you provide the column datatype details for your tables?

Comment: @Love2Learn

AdvTime , ProgStartTime and ProgEndtime are of TIME and Progdate is DATE.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  Distinct mb.Id as mbaid,
        mp.id as mapid, 
        mp.Channel as Channel, 
        mp.Product,
        mp.ProgDate, 
        mp.AdvTime, 
        mb.Channel,  
        mb.ProgStartTime, 
        mb.ProgEndTime, 
        convert(time, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, mb.progStartTime, mb.progEndTime), 0)) as timeDiff 
From    map22 as mp 
Inner   Join mba22 as mb 
        on  mp.ProgDate = mp.ProgDate 
        and mp.Channel= mb.Channel 
        and mp.Product= mb.Product
Where   mp.ProgDate = mb.ProgDate
And     Convert(DateTime,ProgDate) + Convert(DateTime,AdvTime)
            Between 
            Case 
            When ProgEndTime < ProdStartTime And DateDiff(hh,ProgEndTime,ProgStartTime) > 23 Then DateAdd(mi,-5,Convert(DateTime,[Date]) + Convert(DateTime,ProgStartTime))
            When ProgEndTime > ProdStartTime And DateDiff(hh,ProgStartTime,ProgEndTime) > 1 Then DateAdd(mi,-5,Convert(DateTime,[Date]) + Convert(DateTime,ProgStartTime)) 
            Else Convert(DateTime,[Date]) + Convert(DateTime,ProgStartTime) End
            And 
            Case 
            When ProgEndTime < ProdStartTime And DateDiff(hh,ProgEndTime,ProgStartTime) > 23 Then DateAdd(mi,5,Convert(DateTime,Case When ProgEndTime < ProdStartTime Then DateAdd(dd,1,[Date]) Else [Date] End) + Convert(DateTime,ProgEndTime))  
            When ProgEndTime > ProdStartTime And DateDiff(hh,ProgStartTime,ProgEndTime) > 1 Then DateAdd(mi,5,Convert(DateTime,Case When ProgEndTime < ProdStartTime Then DateAdd(dd,1,[Date]) Else [Date] End) + Convert(DateTime,ProgEndTime))  
            Else (Case When ProgEndTime < ProdStartTime Then DateAdd(dd,1,Convert(DateTime,[Date])) Else Convert(DateTime,[Date]) End) + Convert(DateTime,ProgEndTime) End
Order By mp.Id Asc
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but the five minute buffer is required for only when duration [progstarttime -progendtime] is less than or equal to one hour.
And also am not able to match the next day value
i.e 00:05:08 with 23:00:00 to 02:00:00,

Comment: Can you give me an example of inputs that it is missing?